# Black bar covering my y labels for matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I recently started using python for a project, so I apologize in advance for my inexperience.
I am working with the dataset ML1, for each user within the dataset I have to count how many ratings he has expressed. Then I have to sort them out and calculate various statistical functions. After doing this I have to create a graph where it shows on the x= users axis sorted by ratings and y= number of ratings.

```
get_id_user = lambda col: (line.split('::')[col-1] for line in open('../dataset-movie/ml-1m/users.dat'))
get_id_rating = lambda col: (line.split('::')[col-1] for line in open('../dataset-movie/ml-1m/ratings.dat'))
users_id = list(get_id_user(1))
ratings_id = list(get_id_rating(1))
users_rating_match = {}

for index in users_id:
    users_rating_match[index] = ratings_id.count(index)

sorted_users = {k: v for k, v in sorted(users_rating_match.items(), key=lambda v: v[1], reverse=True)}
x = list(sorted_users.keys())
y = list(sorted_users.values())

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('Users sorted by rating')
plt.title('User distribution')
plt.show()
```

This is my code,Briefly, I read the columns I need from the file .dat. I insert those values into two lists and associate them with a dictionary. Then I order the dictionary and build a graph with the specifications above.
When I show the graph, black bars covering my y labels for matplotlib plot certainly because of the high number of values.
I tried to put into practice some solutions of other posts, but without success. Can someone explain/show me how to solve this problem?
[picture_problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Odp4.png)

Comment: I think that's because all the information that contains y-axis labels. 
Have you tried `ax.set_yticks()` function for distanciate y-axis ticks?

Comment: @MiguelGonzalez no, I did not know this function. I now read the documentation and look for a solution. Thanks for the suggestion,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a black bar, it's a bunch of labels on top of each other. With this y axis array, matplotlib (which I assume you are using) has difficulties in suggesting a good and readable number of ticks along the y axis. I can't really tell from your code, but it can happen if the values in the array are not completely numerical. Look at `set_yticks()` and `set_yticklabels()` and see if that helps.